# Using Jaxb Schema with Spring WS: Issues upon Unmarshalling the response

Tags: xsd, jaxb, spring-ws

I have a XML Schema where I've declared all the Requests and Responses objects.

```
-------- For Actual Object -------
<xs:complexType name="conversation">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="participants" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

-------- For Request -----------
<xs:element name="GetListRequest">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="userId" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="date" type="xs:long" />
<xs:element name="dateTo" type="xs:long" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

-------- For Response -----------
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="GetListResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="conversations" type="hmp:conversation" minOccurs="0"      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But I need to create a new deletion request and want only the number of rows deleted as a reponse back. So, I have created the following:

```
-------- For DELETION  ( I only need to retrieve the number of rows deleted) -------
<xs:element name="deleted" type="xs:integer"/>

-------- For Response -----------
<xs:element name="GetDelConversationListResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="deletes" type="hmp:deleted" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But its complaining about cannot resolve the name hmp:deleted. I believe I need to add this in the WSDL or something?? Could somebody pls help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `type="hmp:deleted"`, then there must be a corresponding type defined in your schema, which you don't have (you've defined an element called `deleted`, but not a type).

You should be able to do this, which is simpler:

```
<xs:element name="GetDelConversationListResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="delete" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Absolutely spot-on.. Thanks for your prompt reply

Comment: Also, I'm using Objects as messages from client to service server. How should the endpoint of the service be configured so that the service would be found? Should I be using @PayloadRoot? It seems  seems unfitting here because I'm only returning a integer value and not a xml schema

Comment: @Global: You *are* using an xml schema, it's just a very simple one.